# How use custom libraries in Kohana 3

Tags: php, oop, kohana-3, autoloader

I am trying to include a user library that includes some user related functions such as checking if the user is authenticated and such. Now I am trying to make usage of the Kohana autoloader, but can't seem to get it working.

I have the library placed under application/classes/library

```
class User {
 public function is_alive()
 {
   $session = Session::instance();
   $data = $session->get('alive');

   if(isset($data))
   {
    return true;
   }
   else
   {
    return false;
   }
 }
}
```

And I try to call the library with

```
$user = new User;
```

But it doesn't seem to do the trick.

How can I call a custom library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have the library placed under application/classes/library

Place the library in `/application/classes/`.

Otherwise, you have to place this in your controller:

```
public function before() {
    require Kohana::find_file('classes', 'library/User');
}
```

You can read about this [here](http://kohanaframework.org/guide/api/Controller#before).

Now you can do the same as before, with `User.php` inside the directory `library`.