# Require Once Generates Errors in Kohana v3.3.1

Tags: php, kohana-3

How do I `require_once` in my controller, a third party class that I put in `kohana\vendor\twitter-api-php`? I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767991/how-use-custom-libraries-in-kohana-3) which was similar but I kept getting errors (see below). My project's file structure is as follows:

```
kohana
- application
- modules
- system
- vendor
```

I keep getting these errors

```
 Warning: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'require_once(C:\wamp\www\kohana): failed to open stream: Permission denied' in C:\wamp\www\kohana\application\classes\Controller\Twitter.php:8 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp\www\kohana\application\classes\Controller\Twitter.php(8): Kohana_Core::error_handler(2, 'require_once(C:...', 'C:\wamp\www\koh...', 8, Array) #1 C:\wamp\www\kohana\application\classes\Controller\Twitter.php(8): Controller_Twitter::before() #2 C:\wamp\www\kohana\system\classes\Kohana\Controller.php(69): Controller_Twitter->before() #3 [internal function]: Kohana_Controller->execute() #4 C:\wamp\www\kohana\system\classes\Kohana\Request\Client\Internal.php(97): ReflectionMethod->invoke(Object(Controller_Twitter)) #5 C:\wamp\www\kohana\system\classes\Kohana\Request\Client.php(114): Kohana_Request_Client_Internal->execute_request(Object(Request), Object(Response)) #6 C:\wamp\www\kohana\system\classes\Kohana\Request.php(986): Kohana_Request_Client->execute(Object(Request)) #7 C:\wamp\www\kohana\index.p in C:\wamp\www\kohana\application\classes\Controller\Twitter.php on line 8
```

and this error

```
Fatal error: Controller_Twitter::before(): Failed opening required '' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\kohana\application\classes\Controller\Twitter.php on line 8
```

Here is my code

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die ('No direct script access.');

class Controller_Twitter extends Controller {

    public function before()
    {
        // require_once(APPPATH.'vendor/twitter-api-php/TwitterAPIExchange.php');
        require_once Kohana::find_file('vendor/twitter-api-php', 'TwitterAPIExchange');
    }

    public function action_index()
    {

        $view = new View('twitter/index');
        $this->response->body($view);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `vendor` folder inside the `application` folder.

The location of the `application`, `modules` and `system` folders can be set in `index.php` and will be stored in the `APPPATH`, `MODPATH` and `SYSPATH` constants. Kohana::find_files() will look in `APPPATH`, then in all the loaded modules under `MODPATH` (ok, modules can be located anywhere, but I am assuming they are all under `MODPATH` in your case) and finally `SYSPATH`. Kohana::find_files() won't magically look anywhere else.

Also, why not put the require_once outside the class defenition? Like this.

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die ('No direct script access.');

// require_once(APPPATH.'vendor/twitter-api-php/TwitterAPIExchange.php');
require_once Kohana::find_file('vendor/twitter-api-php', 'TwitterAPIExchange');

class Controller_Twitter extends Controller {

    public function action_index()
    {
        $view = new View('twitter/index');
        $this->response->body($view);
    }
}
```